# Is it possible to use a formula or some sort of AND OR condition to filter an Excel table?

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, formula, array-formulas

When I use the Autofilter feature it is basically doing an AND operation. Is it possible to use an OR operation when I autofilter two or more columns?

For example for the following table I need all with Gender = `Male` **OR** Role = `Teacher`:

```
Gender    Role
Male      Student
Male      Teacher
Female    Student
Male      Teacher
Female    Teacher
Female    Teacher
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try a layout like this:

[image: SO26417874 first example]

and an Advanced Filter like this:

[image: SO26417874 second example]

Take note of the syntax in `A2` (and `B3` should correspond).

For further [details](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/advanced-filter.html).

Comment: loved this solution. It is the simplest. Thank you!

Comment: I agree. I ended up using @cb7 solution as I had to try out different scenarios. Advance filter would not lend for that.

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a new column and use it as a pass/fail for your criteria? For instance, if you want to display all rows where Gender=Male OR Role=Teacher, try this:

```
=IF(OR(A2="Male", B2="Teacher"),1,0)
```

Now use autofilter on this column to just display the 1's.

Comment: Next best solution, which will work if I have to switch between different filter combinations on the fly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's using array formula (Works only on *XL2007* and up)

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$7,SMALL(IF(($A$1:$A$7=$D$1)+($B$1:$B$7=$E$1),ROW($A$1:$A$7),1E+99),ROW($A1)),COLUMN(A$1)),"")`

Data should be set-up like this:

[image]

You enter the formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in *Cell D2*.
Then copy the formula to the remaining cells. 
The highlighted green cells in **D1** and **E1** are your criteria. HTH.